# Error:(555, 5) error: expected enum but got (raw string) bold

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am using custom font style for that created custom xml attributes.already used enum in declared style attributes but still no success. Its seems some messed up and facing the below-mentioned issue.
Facing this issue:

**Error:(555, 5) error: expected enum but got (raw string) bold.**

attrs.xml file is

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
    <attr name="font_name" format="string" />
    <attr name="font_style" format="enum">
        <enum name="normal" value="0" />
        <enum name="bold" value="1" />
        <enum name="italic" value="2" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

I created styles for Textview.

```
<style name="STextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="font_style">bold</item>
</style>
```

It was working earlier recently updated compile sdk version in build.gradle to 27 and stated facing this issue.

Comment: change attribute key name to some another name that should not be related to "font_style" and "fontStyle" bcz these key has used by android in android support lib. for reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<item name="font_style">bold</item>
```

to

```
<item name="font_style">@bold</item>
```